# ExpressionEngine Channel not appearing in select list on entry

Tags: php, expressionengine, legacy

I've set up a new channel on my local environment but cannot seem to replicate what I've done on my live environment (probably leaving it too long in between to remember!) For some reason the Channel I've created doesn't show up in the select list for channel on entries on my live site.

I believe I've set up the channel itself the same on both instances but something can't be right. Does anyone have any ideas on what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

Does your channel appear in the channels section in the CP? And does your member group have rights to publish into that channel?
You can reach more EE devs by posting here: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/ or on the [EE Forums](https://expressionengine.com/forums) or on [Slack](https://eecms.slack.com)

Comment: Thanks Jelle. I think I've figured this out, I need to select the channel I created as page type when I create a page. I don't think there is a way to change a page type in EE once you've selected it is there?

Comment: Oh i think you are using Structure? If so: yes, you'll need to set it in the structure channel settings